# Widgets to list files with gtk

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I am creating an application which is going to list a bunch of files. I would like to list files like fileroller, but I don't know how. I guess I need to create a 2xn (name, size) grid, but I don't know how to make entries appear light->dark->light per line, and how to create a "fat" bar above it. Can anyone tell me what sort of widgets I need to combine to create something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a [GtkTreeView](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html) with a GtkListStore, that should give you everything you need. If you've never used it, you should start with reading the [Tree and List Widget Overview](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/TreeWidget.html) and be prepared to do some googling even afterwards -- it's the most complex widget in the toolkit.

The treeview can have a header, and the alternating light/dark rows are typically achieved with `gtk_tree_view_set_rules_hint (treeview, TRUE)` -- but please read the documentation, 'rules hint' is a semantic thing not specifically a visual setting.