# How to alternate light/dark rows in GtkTreeView?

Tags: css, c, gtk, gtk3

I have read, and tried the existing solutions for this question, and I can't get them to work. I was hoping someone could point out what I'm doing wrong, or tell me why those solutions aren't working anymore.

- https://thegnomejournal.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/styling-gtk-with-css/ (5 years old)
- [Widgets to list files with gtk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367427/widgets-to-list-files-with-gtk/21367649#21367649) (2 years old)
- [How do you change alternating background row colors of a gtk.TreeView in pygtk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036812/how-do-you-change-alternating-background-row-colors-of-a-gtk-treeview-in-pygtk) (4 years old)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/285559/how-to-reenable-alternating-grey-lines-in-nautilus-files-3-6-list-view (3 years old)

I wanted to be sure these solutions weren't working, so I made a style sheet like this:

```
GtkTreeView row {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
GtkTreeView row:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #FF00FF;
}
GtkTreeView row:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #00FFFF;
}
```

with garish colors, just to make the difference in row color really obvious. Then, I made a little application to load up a tree view:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;
  gtk_init(&argc,&argv);
  //GtkBuilder* b = gtk_builder_new_from_file("derp.glade.xml");
  GtkWidget* top = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  GtkListStore* items = gtk_list_store_new(2,
                                           G_TYPE_STRING,
                                           G_TYPE_STRING);

  GtkWidget* view = gtk_tree_view_new_with_model(GTK_TREE_MODEL(items));
  gtk_tree_view_insert_column_with_attributes
    (GTK_TREE_VIEW(view),
     0,
     "Herp",
     gtk_cell_renderer_text_new(),
     "text",0,
     NULL);
  gtk_tree_view_insert_column_with_attributes
    (GTK_TREE_VIEW(view),
     1,
     "Derp",
     gtk_cell_renderer_text_new(),
     "text",1,
     NULL);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(top),view);
  GtkCssProvider* prov = gtk_css_provider_new();
  gtk_css_provider_load_from_path
    (prov,
    "derp.css",
     NULL);
  gtk_style_context_add_provider
    (gtk_widget_get_style_context(view),
     GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(prov),
     GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);

  GtkTreeIter iter;
  gtk_tree_model_get_iter_first(GTK_TREE_MODEL(items),&iter);

  for(i=0;i<3;++i) {
    gtk_list_store_insert_with_values
      (items,&iter,0,
       0, "Row",
       1, "Row",
       -1);
  }
  gtk_widget_show_all(top);
  gtk_main();
  return 0;
}
```

compiled with:

```
gcc -o test teststyle.c `pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --cflags --libs`
```

When I run the application, the three rows display with #00FFFF as the background color. They don't alternate. They only take on the color from the "row:nth-child(odd)" section, and even the even rows take on that color. Messing with the css file can do some funny things too. Switching odd and even, for instance:

```
GtkTreeView row {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
GtkTreeView row:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #FF00FF;
}
GtkTreeView row:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #00FFFF;
}
```

Now all the rows display as #FF00FF, with no alternation. I think GTK is just completely failing to read the pseudo-classes somehow, accidentally turning "GtkTreeView row:nth-child(odd)" into "GtkTreeView row" and completely missing the "nth-child(even)" selector entirely. If I remove the odd selector and only have even:

```
GtkTreeView row {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
GtkTreeView row:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #FF00FF;
}
```

Now it's got a background color of #FF0000, so it's ignoring (even) rules entirely.

I tried setting the rules hint on the tree view, and it didn't do anything, other than complain that setting the rules hint was deprecated. I'm using GTK 3.18.9, on a basic Arch system, with XFCE as the window manager. Am I doing anything wrong here? Or is my version of GTK just messed up, somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I think only 2 blocks are enough something like these

```
GtkTreeView row:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #FF00FF;
}
GtkTreeView row:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #00FFFF;
}
```

below an example in python, tested ok before answer

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: ISO-8859-1 -*-
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Gdk

window = Gtk.Window()
window.connect("destroy", lambda q: Gtk.main_quit())

liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str, int)
liststore.append(["Oranges", 5])
liststore.append(["Apples", 3])
liststore.append(["Bananas", 1])
liststore.append(["Tomatoes", 4])
liststore.append(["Cucumber", 1])
liststore.append(["potatoes", 10])
liststore.append(["apricot", 100])

treeview = Gtk.TreeView(model=liststore)
treeview.set_rules_hint( True )
window.add(treeview)

treeviewcolumn = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Item")
treeview.append_column(treeviewcolumn)
cellrenderertext = Gtk.CellRendererText()
treeviewcolumn.pack_start(cellrenderertext, True)
treeviewcolumn.add_attribute(cellrenderertext, "text", 0)

treeviewcolumn = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Quantity")
treeview.append_column(treeviewcolumn)
cellrenderertext = Gtk.CellRendererText()
treeviewcolumn.pack_start(cellrenderertext, True)
treeviewcolumn.add_attribute(cellrenderertext, "text", 1)
css_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
css = """
                /* font operate on entire GtkTreeView not for selected row */
                GtkTreeView {font-weight: bold;font: Sans 20;font-style: italic;}
                GtkTreeView row:nth-child(even) {
                background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear,
                                                   left top,
                   left bottom,
                   from (#d0e4f7),
                   color-stop (0.5, darker (#d0e4f7)),
                   to (#fdffff));
                }
                GtkTreeView row:nth-child(odd) {
                background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear,
                                                   left top,
                   left bottom,
                   from (yellow),
                   color-stop (0.5, darker (yellow)),
                   to (#fdffff));
                }
                /* next line only border action operate */
                GtkTreeView:selected{color: white; background: green; border-width: 1px; border-color: black;}
                /* next line for Gtk.TreeViewColumn */
                column-header .button{color: white; background: purple;}

            """
css_provider.load_from_data(css)
screen = Gdk.Screen.get_default()
style_context = window.get_style_context()
style_context.add_provider_for_screen(screen, css_provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)

window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Code example does not work  "Traceback (most recent call last):   File "zebragtk.py", line 58, in <module>
    css_provider.load_from_data(css)
TypeError: Item 0: Must be number, not str"

Comment: I'm little surprised. My gtk is Version GtK 3.8.10 and python is 2.7.6. Code is running ok. I don't know what is about. Is there anybody can explain it?

Comment: I'm using GTK 3.18.2 . Sounded familiar set_rules_hint was depreciated in GTK 3.14  https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.16/GtkTreeView.html#gtk-tree-view-set-rules-hint

Comment: Took the time to implement this in C: http://pastebin.com/wRGBxHYB compiled with ```gcc -o derpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` derp.c``` and it still ignores the `(even)` selector. I have GTK 3.18.9. No clue why the python won't work, but I suspect heavily layered abstract interfaces are the culprit.

Comment: Same thing for me in a GTK# project.  The rows do not alternate with the above CSS code.

Comment: I don't understand. Is this a bug? Any link to it?

Comment: @Manmax Your Python is 2.7.6? Then why you specified python3 in the shebang line? By the way. Your code isn'T working for me, too.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bug. In [this example](https://github.com/Xoristzatziki/GtkDataGrid/blob/master/basicdatagrid.py) `row:nth-child` is applied to different GtkTreeView's.